# Rails how to enable POST for all controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Am usng rails 4 and I have an API controller with many actions. like:

```
def authenticate
    ........
end

def get_data
    ...........
end

....
```

How do i enable POST request for all actions in the API controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the route as 'post' in routes.rb

```
resources :controller_name do
  member do
    post 'authenticate'
    post 'get_data' 
  end
```